# H2 WebServer open web console with prefilled informations

Tags: java, console, webserver, h2

I am creating desktop application with embedded H2 database and I would like to take advantage of the H2 web server so that user can use H2 web console.

I do not have any problem to do so but I would like to specify the connection information for the user on the consoles login screen (url, user..) or open the database for user directly.

```
final Server s = Server.createWebServer();
s.start().openBrowser(s.getURL());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible out of the box IMHO. The java code you wrote is running on the **server** side, but selecting in H2 console a connection (could be H2, postgresql, etc...) requires interaction on the **client** side.

Possible alternatives:

1- You could write a selenium script to open this for you. This is the easiest way forward and you might add it to your java code with cautions (avoid race conditions).

2- You could tweak the file $HOME/.h2.server.properties in order to have only one possible connection, but you would still need to enter the credentials once and have them saved by your browser.

3- Another alternative would be for you to tweak the H2 console itself to give access to the database, but this would be a security hole. I guess this is why it's not possible to do so even by configuration.

Good luck.